# Nested for-loops: how to build tuple from all indices?

Tags: python, nested-loops

Say I have 4 arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I could iterate like so:

```
tups = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        for k in c:
            for l in d:
                t = i,j,k,l
                tups.append(t)
```

`tups` would then be an array of tuples and  will look something like this:

```
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
1,1,1,3
...
1,1,1,6
...
```

This seems rather long winded and I feel that there should be a faster/more efficient way of doing this, but I'm not really a python expert.

How can I make this faster, without looping over each array? Is there some functional approach which I can use?

Comment: Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: @Barmar actually, this would be `itertools.product`. While `itertools.product` would be slightly faster, from an algorithmic complexity POV, it's just as inefficient anways.

Comment: Yeah, got confused between them. I remembered there was some itertools method for it.

Comment: Please note, while this looks long-winded, that's because *it is*. What you want is the cartesian product, and that is fundamentally inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: a=[1,2,3]

In [3]: b=[1,2,3,4]

In [4]: c=[1,2,3,4,5]

In [5]: d=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [6]: for i in itertools.product(a,b,c,d):
...:     print(repr(i))
...:     
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 4)
(1, 1, 1, 5)
(1, 1, 1, 6)
(1, 1, 2, 1)
...
(3, 4, 5, 4)
(3, 4, 5, 5)
(3, 4, 5, 6)
```